# error LNK1120: 1 unresolved external - VS13 C

Tags: c, visual-studio, winapi, visual-c++, unresolved-external

I have tried to compile this code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <commctrl.h>


#define ID_TABCTRL 1
#define ID_EDIT 2
#define BTN_ADD 3
#define BTN_DEL 4
#define BTN_CLR 5
#define MAX_TAB_LEN 15

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
HWND hTab, hEdit;

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {

    MSG  msg;
    WNDCLASSW wc = { 0 };
    wc.lpszClassName = L"Tab control";
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hbrBackground = GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_3DFACE);
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(0, IDC_ARROW);

    RegisterClassW(&wc);
    CreateWindowW(wc.lpszClassName, L"Tab control",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,
        100, 100, 380, 230, 0, 0, hInstance, 0);

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {

        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return (int)msg.wParam;
}

WINCOMMCTRLAPI BOOL WINAPI InitCommonControlsEx(_In_ const INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX *picce);

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg,
    WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {

    TCITEMW tie;
    wchar_t text[4];
    LRESULT count, id;
    INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX icex;

    switch (msg) {

    case WM_CREATE:

        icex.dwSize = sizeof(INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX);
        icex.dwICC = ICC_TAB_CLASSES;
        InitCommonControlsEx(&icex);

        hTab = CreateWindowW(WC_TABCONTROLW, NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
            0, 0, 200, 150, hwnd, (HMENU)ID_TABCTRL, NULL, NULL);

        hEdit = CreateWindowW(WC_EDITW, NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER,
            250, 20, 100, 25, hwnd, (HMENU)ID_EDIT, NULL, NULL);

        SendMessage(hEdit, EM_SETLIMITTEXT, MAX_TAB_LEN, 0);

        CreateWindowW(WC_BUTTONW, L"Add", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON,
            250, 50, 100, 25, hwnd, (HMENU)BTN_ADD, NULL, NULL);

        CreateWindowW(WC_BUTTONW, L"Delete", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON,
            250, 80, 100, 25, hwnd, (HMENU)BTN_DEL, NULL, NULL);

        CreateWindowW(WC_BUTTONW, L"Clear", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON,
            250, 110, 100, 25, hwnd, (HMENU)BTN_CLR, NULL, NULL);
        break;

    case WM_COMMAND:

        switch (LOWORD(wParam)) {

        case BTN_ADD:

            GetWindowTextW(hEdit, text, 250);

            if (lstrlenW(text) != 0) {

                tie.mask = TCIF_TEXT;
                tie.pszText = text;
                count = SendMessageW(hTab, TCM_GETITEMCOUNT, 0, 0);
                SendMessageW(hTab, TCM_INSERTITEMW, count,
                    (LPARAM)(LPTCITEM)&tie);
            }
            break;

        case BTN_DEL:

            id = SendMessageW(hTab, TCM_GETCURSEL, 0, 0);

            if (id != -1) {

                SendMessageW(hTab, TCM_DELETEITEM, 0, id);
            }
            break;

        case BTN_CLR:

            SendMessageW(hTab, TCM_DELETEALLITEMS, 0, 0);
            break;
        }
        break;

    case WM_DESTROY:

        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    }

    return(DefWindowProcW(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam));
}
```

and it seems like this libary:

```
#include <commctrl.h>
```

giving me the following error:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol        __imp__InitCommonControlsEx@4 referenced in function _WndProc@16   C:\Users\User\Desktop\Magshimim\Magshimim EX1\Magshimim EX1\01.obj  Magshimim EX1
```

now the code is an example code from here: http://zetcode.com/gui/winapi/advancedcontrols/

so i figured out that something wrong with my compiler...
can any one help me find the problem and correct it?

edit: 
the question is not a duplicate because the refereed duplicate talks in a very general way about the error itself and as a beginner i dont have the skills to build a proper answer from such a question and because that code is been used by many peoples who check the example i think its impotent to make a specific question

Comment: Did you link the `Comctl32.lib` library, as mandated by the `InitCommonControlsEx` [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775697.aspx)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Either add `#pragma comment(lib, "comctl32.lib")` or adjust the linker settings to link against `comctl32.lib`.

You can check the table at the bottom of a function's [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775697.aspx) to find out, which library you are required to link against. Every Windows application is linked against `kernel32.dll` and every GUI application against `user32.dll`. Anything else needs to be specified explicitly<sup>[1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775697.aspx)</sup>.

---

[1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775697.aspx) There are exceptions, check [IInspectable's comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38317651/error-lnk1120-1-unresolved-external-vs13-c/38317757?noredirect=1#comment64062763_38317757).

Comment: *"Anything else needs to be specified explicitly."* - This is not correct. A wizard-generated default Win32 application in Visual Studio links against a fair number of LIBs (e.g. *gdi32.lib*, *comdlg32.lib*, *shell32.lib*). And then there are libraries that are implicitly linked through their header files (e.g. *SAPI.Lib* through *sapi.h*). While it usually doesn't hurt to explicitly specify linker dependencies, it is not always required.

Comment: @IInspectable I use MinGW and didn't think about Wizard-linked LIBs. I edited the answer to refer to your comment. Thanks :)